# VB perfect function

Tags: vb.net

What is wrong with this perfect number function?
The method is supposed to decide whether the input number is/is not a perfect number. The answer is supposed to be all the perfect numbers from 1 to the input.

For example: 1 - 100 the answer would be 6 and 28

```
Public Function isPerfect(myInput As Integer) As Boolean
    endCounter = myInput \ 2
    sum = 1

    For perfectCounter As Integer = 2 To endCounter
        If myInput Mod perfectCounter = 0 Then
            sum += perfectCounter
            If sum = myInput Then
                Return True
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function


    Private Sub btnPerfect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPerfect.Click
    input = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text)
    msg = "The perfect numbers between 1 and " & input & " are : "

    For inputCounter As Integer = 0 To input
        If isPerfect(inputCounter) = True Then
            msg += inputCounter & " "
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(msg, , "Perfect Number")

    txtNumber.Focus()
    txtNumber.Text = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like your understanding of how to calculate a perfect number is not right.  Can you describe your logic?

Comment: I have the input module the counter and if it equals 0 then that means that it is divisible by that number, so I add that to the sum and I use a for loop to constantly go through till the number. And I return true if it's a Perfect Number. I know I must have calculated it wrong but I can't seem to find where.

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: `a perfect number is a number that is half the sum of all of its positive divisors including itself`. You include the one but not "itself"

Comment: For small numbers, it's easy to go over the code for the function by hand and discover what the problem is.

Comment: @A.S.H I'm getting 6, 24 , 28 496 I don't know why I'm getting the 24

Comment: @user3697824 If I include itself, wouldn't it be over then?

Comment: @boboobobo You should try debugging the program. You get 24 because 1+2+3+4+6+8 = 24.

Comment: Ah. So: 1+2+3+4+6+8 = 24, your loop exits and confirms, it did not realize that there is still another divisor: 12. Conclusion: you should not exit the loop as soon as sum=number, you need to continue summing up divisors until the half of the number and only then check if sum=number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least a couple of problems:

1. You are validating the perfect number ***inside*** the loop, before you've even finished summing the divisors.

For instance...

```
If sum = myInput Then
    Return True
End If
```

The above should be checked ***after*** the loop.

2. More importantly, because you are setting `endCounter` to `myInput \ 2`, you are not summing all the divisors.  Maybe you did this as an optimization. But if so, you forgot something along the way.

A quick fix is to change the `endCounter` assignment to:

```
endCounter = myInput - 1
```

Also, to avoid getting back `1` as a valid perfect number, I would initialize `sum` to `0`, and would start the loop normally at `1` instead of `2`.

So your function could look something like:

```
Public Function isPerfect(myInput As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim endCounter As Integer = myInput - 1
    Dim sum As Integer = 0

    For perfectCounter As Integer = 1 To endCounter
        If myInput Mod perfectCounter = 0 Then
            sum += perfectCounter
        End If
    Next

    Return sum = myInput
End Function
```

I'm sure you could optimize this further if you want to.

(*) Consider turning on `Option Explicit` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help I see what I did wrong now. I didn't realize that I was ending it before validating what was left over.

Comment: Note that the problem with `myInput \ 2` is that it rounds down, not necessarily that you would need to check higher numbers up to `myInput - 1`. `(myInput+1) \ 2` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct implementation of isPerfect:

```
Public Function isPerfect(myInput As Integer) As Boolean
    dim Sum as Integer = 1
    For i as Integer = 2 To myInput / 2
        If myInput Mod i = 0 Then Sum = Sum + i
    Next
    Return Sum = myInput
End Function
```